# Vertical spacing in KOMA

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

This question was revised on the basis of the comments.

I use the `KOMA` script to create the style of my textbook based on the instructions of the typesetter (who never used `LaTeX` but has designed many textbooks in `Indesign`).

The requirements for the vertical spacing are:

- smaller font for figure and table captions
- `1.35` times the font size for line spacing
- half line spacing between paragraphs

Below you can see my implementation of the requirements, which is also MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,parskip=half-]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{9pt}{12.15pt}\selectfont\normalfont}
\setstretch{1.125}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[3]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you have probably noticed, the implementation is quite confusing. I found that the `KOMA` `10pt` option probably set `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont` as the default font. So to get `13.5pt` for line spacing, I use the package setspace and `\setstretch{1.125}` `(12*1.125=1.35)`.

On the other hand, I cannot use the same procedure for captions, because all my attempts to use the analogous procedure `\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont` (`9*1.2=10.8`) and `\setstretch{1.125}` over it failed. So I specified `\fontsize{9pt}{12.15pt}\selectfont` instead (`9*1.35=12.15`).

This is quite inconsistent and probably should not be done this way. Could you please tell me how this should be done with the `KOMA` script?

[image]

Comment: In KOMA you can use `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\setstretch{1.125}}` to change the line spacing in headings, and `\addtokomafont{caption}{\setstretch{1.125}}` to change the line spacing in figure/table captions.

Comment: @Skillmon This isn't working well, because I already use command `\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\normalfont}`.  If I add `\setstretch{1.125}` at the end, then font reverts back to `10pt`.  If I add `\setstretch{1.125}` in the beginning, then stretch reverts back to `1`.  How can I do both?

Comment: You force the line spacing with your `\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}`, the latter value is the line spacing. Maybe the size-reset can be fixed by loading `scrhack` before `setspace` (but I didn't test).

Comment: @Skillmon It does not work.  But `\fontsize{9pt}{12.15pt}\selectfont\normalfont` works.  (`12.15pt` = `1.35` * `9pt`)  Is this regular way to do it?

Comment: It is one way to do it on a local scope.

Comment: @Skillmon It is all, at least to me, a bit confusing.  It seems that the regular text is `\fontisize{10pt}{12pt}`, so I have to use stretch `1.125` to get `1.35` line spacing.  On the other hand, the stretch for caption text is `1` and there is no way to change it, so I achieve `1.35` line spacing by `\fontsize{9pt}{12.15pt}`.

Comment: Would you post a minimal working example, please? Otherwise all comments here are guesses. Skillmons first comment was a waste of time, because you already had some settings in your code.

Comment: BTW: KOMA-Script does not have options `singlespacing`, `onehalfspacing` or `doublespacing`. IMHO these are options of package `setspace`. Package `setspace` is completely independent from KOMA-Script.

Comment: @KeksDose Done as asked, please reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the easiest way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,parskip=half-]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[font={small, stretch=1.35}, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\setstretch{1.35}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[3]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\setstretch` you could use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{document}{\begin{spacing}{1.35}}
  \AtEndEnvironment{document}{\end{spacing}}
```

However, this factor of 1.35 may be or may be not what your typesetter had in mind. Should the linespread between lines in the caption be exactly like in normal text or a little bit less because the font is smaller?

Comment: Well, to be precise, the book designer just told me that they normally use a line spacing of 1.5 times the font size, but I should print different spacings and see for myself. 1.2x (LateX default ) does indeed look too dense, but 1.5x looks too sparse, so I went for the compromise 1.35x. I think this should be the same for all fonts used. So the spacing for caption text should be 9/10 of the spacing for normal text.

Comment: @Pygmalion That's how it is.

Comment: Actually, I tested your solution and you should have used `1.125` instead of `1.35`, because the starting point is `1.2`.  What I like about your solution is that it has the same multiplication number for regular and caption text.  What I don't like is that it uses additional package and it does not produce *exactly* the same result (the difference is about 1% in caption text spacing).  The big question is, which solution will give more consistent results when LaTeX will try to stretch or compress the page vertically?  Or is it the same?